# How can i retrieve most similar images inside a Support Vector Machine's class?

Tags: svm, scikit-learn

When i predict the class that belongs an image in SVM in scikit learn

```
...
print "Predicting on 1 sample"
print "Input features:"
fv = [0.16666666666628771, 5.169878828456423e-26, 2.584939414228212e-22, 1.0, 1.0000000000027285]
print fv
print "Predicted class index:"
print clf.predict([fv])
```

Output:

```
Predicted class index:
[5]
```

How can i get its most 5 similar images inside its class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't thing you can get a similarity measure between samples from a SVM, only the distance from a sample to the hyperplane that is used for classification.

You could calculate the euclidean distances between the feature vectors of the images using the [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) method. The 5 images with the shortest distance to your target image can be considered most similar. I hope that helps.

Comment: Scikit-learn's `sklearn.metrics` also contains a bunch of distance and similarity metrics, among them the kernels used by SVMs to compute similarities.

Comment: You're reffering at http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel if i use a rbf kernel in my svc etc. ?